# TypeError: context must be specified" in zmq unpickling

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, chat, pyzmq

I am trying to create a very simple chat. Using the PyZMQ library. And since sockets are not threadsafe I am using two sockets and one thread running on each. One checking for incoming messages, and one to send messages.

But my program is giving me, error messages:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1089, in load_newobj
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1089, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
  File "zmq\backend\cython\socket.pyx", line 279, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.__cinit__ (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3456)
TypeError: context must be specified
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
  File "zmq\backend\cython\socket.pyx", line 279, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.__cinit__ (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3456)
TypeError: context must be specified
```

I can not figure out why I am getting them, or how to solve it.

Also is my logic wrong here?:

> We start the server which creates a socket and binds it to a port. Then It listens to that sockets for messages/connections. Then we create another socket and binds it to the same port. We create a new thread that makes it so that we wait for messages to be recieved on the first socket to then be sent to the second one.
>   Then we have a client who connects to the first socket. We create a new thread for it so it can listen on the other socket for incoming messages, and thus it can use the first thread to send messages through the first socket.

**server.py**

```
from communication import Communication
from multiprocessing import Process
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        port = "5556"

    c = Communication(port)
    c.bind()
    recieverP = Process(target=c.reciever)
    recieverP.start()
    print("first process")

    c2 = Communication(port)
    c2.connect()
    senderP = Process(target=c2.sender)
    senderP.start()
    print("second process")
```

**client.py**

```
from communication import Communication
from multiprocessing import Process
import zmq
import random
import sys
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        port = "5556"

    c = Communication(port)
    c.connect()


    recieverP = Process(target=c.reciever, args=())
    senderP = Process(target=c.sender,args=())
    recieverP.start()
    senderP.start()
```

**communications.py**

```
import zmq

class Communication:
    def __init__(self, port):
        context = zmq.Context.instance()
        self.port = port
        self.socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)

    def connect(self):
        self.socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % self.port)

    def bind(self):
        self.socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % self.port)

    def sender(self):
        while True:
            msg = raw_input("> ")
            self.socket.send(msg)

    def reciever(self):
        while True:
            msg = self.socket.recv()
            print("> " + msg)
```

Comment: ...also, errors should be given as text in the question, not images hosted off-site (a question needs to include errors **directly in the question itself** to be considered complete). Microsoft's terminal *does* allow copy/paste, so there's no reason you can't reach that original text.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are correct. I will edit in the errors. I was not sure what to title my question, since I dont know what error it causes, `TypeError` ?

Comment: "TypeError: context must be specified" in zmq unpickling <- might be my first shot at a better title.

Comment: ...it sounds like Dunes has an answer that avoids the need for pickling/unpickling altogether; an answer that makes your objects picklable may also be possible.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thx! I edited my post. Yes I am hoping that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully working version below. I made a few changes:

1. I used threads instead of processes, as suggested by @Dunes.
2. I combined `client.py` and `server.py` into a single `app.py` with a "role" parameter. (This was just to avoid a lot of duplicate code.)
3. I handled `KeyboardException`s in the main thread so you can Ctrl+C to exit.
4. I dropped the "> " prefix on lines, since it led to confusing output. (When you type something in the other app, you'd get output like "> > hello".)
5. I took out the `c2` that was in `server.py`. I'm not sure what the purpose of that was, and I don't know if that's expected to work. (Seems like you were `connect`ing instead of `bind`ing?)
6. I fixed the spelling of "receiver" everywhere because it was bothering me. :-)
7. I made `port` an `int` instead of a `str`, because it is. :-)

app.py:

```
import argparse
from threading import Thread
import time

from communication import Communication

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("role", help="either 'client' or 'server'", choices=['client', 'server'])
    parser.add_argument("--port", "-p", type=int, help="port number", default=5556)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    c = Communication(args.port)
    if args.role == 'client':
        c.connect()
    else:
        c.bind()

    receiverP = Thread(target=c.receiver)
    senderP = Thread(target=c.sender)
    receiverP.daemon = True
    senderP.daemon = True
    try:
        receiverP.start()
        senderP.start()
        while True:
            time.sleep(100)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

communication.py:

```
import zmq

class Communication:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port
        context = zmq.Context.instance()
        self.socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)

    def connect(self):
        self.socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%d" % self.port)

    def bind(self):
        self.socket.bind("tcp://*:%d" % self.port)

    def sender(self):
        while True:
            self.socket.send(raw_input())

    def receiver(self):
        while True:
            print(self.socket.recv())
```

Comment: First, Thank you! Secondly: 1. So this all comes down to processors can not be serialized? Would it be possible to solve this with processes instead of threads? 5. I had `c2` so that could open another socket and run one of my threads on it. And yes, in that case maybe I should have `bind`ed them both? Or maybe my logic here is wrong :).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use multiple processes like you were doing, since each process needs to access the same 0mq socket (and I don't see how a socket could be shared between the two processes).

Comment: Late question: Why are you using both threads as daemon threads? My guess would be that we are running 3 threads, one for `sender` one for `reciever` and one that is running our program. So when we close the program (and thus, the "main" thread) the rest will close. But I am unsure if we are actually doing 3 threads? If we are only doing 2 threads then only one of them would need to be a daemon thread, right?

Comment: There are indeed three threads. I made those two daemon threads so the program would exit when the main thread exits. From the documentation: "A thread can be flagged as a 'daemon thread'. The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left."

Answer (score 1):

These are processes not threads. The problem occurs because in the background Python has to send a copy of your `Communication` object to the child process. However, your object contains socket objects that cannot be serialised. Use `threading` and the `Thread` object in place of `Process` and you won't run into this problem. This is because threads run in the same process.

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing `recieverP = threading.Thread(target=c.reciever)` instead. And now, atleast, I am being able to create my threads. But I get another error now: `Internal assertation: nBytes ==.....`. I googled it, and found this: https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1573. So it seems that  this error occures if I am using multiple threads on the same socket. But I dont do that, right? I am creating a new instans here: `c2 = Communication(port)` and therefore a new socket. They are connected to the same port though. Could that be the fault?

Comment: @FelixRosén, threads share the file descriptor table with their parent processes. If a thread opens a file, every other thread (and its parent) has it open too.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok! But how can I then have two threads running on two diffrent sockets? Maybe I need to use the `multiprocess` package after all.